# Blob type not supported

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using ***Nativescript 5*** and ***Angulat 4***, and I am trying to download an image using a get request using ***@angular/http***

```
getImageFile(path){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

        return this.http.get((encodeURI(this.serverUrl + path)),{method: RequestMethod.Get,
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob, headers: headers })
            .map(res =>  res);
}
```

But it returns

```
Error: Response type of 'blob' not supported.
```

So I remove `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob` and it works.

But when trying to get the information

```
this.myGetService.getImageFile('api/imagen/')
        .subscribe(
            response =>{
                try{
                    var blob = new Blob([response.blob()], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
                }catch(err){
                    console.log("Super Error !!!!", err);
                }
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("Error Request: " + error);
            });
```

Now it throws an exception.

```
Super Error !!!! ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Blob
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1202) to support `Blob` format with the `HttpClient` in {N} Angular.

A workaround could be using the `getFile` method on the default [Http](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http) module.

Comment: To bad!! Thanks, I had to modify my service and send an image coded on Base64 and decoded in the client.